# Why Gnome/Ubuntu use SAMBA as default sharing service?

Tags: gnome, samba, nfs

and not NFS?

click on a folder and select proprieties, tab "share".

Answer (score 4):

- Most Ubuntu users will be sharing
  there network with at least one
  Windows or Apple machine and samba is
  the only fully featured sharing
  service which is capable of being
  accessed by the majority of computers
  what ever operating system they
  happen to be using.
- Also the GUI method of setting up
  shares is the easiest to do for
  someone new to Ubuntu which means
  that they will probably have been
  using one of the afore mentioned
  OS's. Once you are a more experienced
  user you will probably have figured
  out that Ubuntu is the best OS in the
  world and will have wiped and
  Installed it on all their other
  systems so no need for samba any more.

Just remember we were all nube's once (*holds hand to chest*)

Answer (score 2):

Because all OS'es can handle SMB, not all, I am looking at you Windows, can handle NFS.

Ubuntu is meant to be easy to use, so it uses default values that will work the best for the most people. You can always define a NFS share yourself.

Answer (score 0):

And (as suppliment to the other answers) SMB (at al) is an open, royalty free specification. Its origins might be in the depths of Redmond but thanks in part to the EU and in greater part to the fantastic work of the Samba project and its contributors, is a highly compatible simple sharing service that, when it works, just works.

Don't get me wrong, NFS is great. It's faster and lighter than Samba... But try getting three different operating systems talking to each other over it.

There's also the issue of needing to be root to set NFS shares. Not an insurmountable issue in the scale of things but a low priority goal in the scope of the NFS project when Samba already does the job so well.

Comment: "depths of Redmond" kind of like the "depths of Mordor" perhaps

Comment: windows can handle NFS: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324055